# How can I connect to a website hosting my website via socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to connect to my website, though I see that sockets can only connect to IPv4 and IPv6, but when I use tracert (mywebsite.000webhostapp.com) it gets the domain of 000webhostapp.com, not the IPv4 of my website. I am doing this:

`SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com");`

but I can only connect to the IPv4. How can I connect to the hostname (like how I am doing)? 
Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *mywebsite.000webhostapp.com* has the same IP as *000webhostapp.com*, that's mean your website is located on the same server as your webhost. You don't have a dedicated server for your website.

So if you don't want to make complicated c-code to resolve the DNS name, your can directly connect with its IP (by the way, using `ping` to resolve it is often more quicker than using `tracert`).

Then your webhost will use virtualhost to know which website is accessed. It is using the `Host` field from your HTTP request to identify which website is wanted. For example, your HTTP request could begin like that:

```
   GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
   Host: mywebsite.000webhostapp.com
```

You can see more information about virtual hosting here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting

Comment: I have tried to add this header, but what would I connect the socket to?

Comment: to the IP of _000webhost.app.com_ after its DNS resolution with your favorite tool (like ping)

Answer (score 0):

`inet_addr()` only parses IP addresses. [`getaddrinfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx) will look up DNS records (both IPv4 (A) and IPv6 (AAAA) records, depending on the hints you pass in).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it..

`inet_addr()` function converts the Internet host address from IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary data in network byte order. (from documentation).

But you can do it another way.

Get the ip address from the URL first.

first get the `hostent` structure from `gethostbyname`:

```
struct hostent *hEnt;
hEnt = gethostbyname("MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com");
```

`h_addr_list` of `hostent` is a NULL-terminated array of pointers to
host IP addresses.

Get the ip address from above said array and use it.

Below link has example.
Search for `gethostbyname`

http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/

Comment: Note that `gethostbyname()` is deprecated. It's not re-entrant (at least on other OSes; Windows uses thread-local storage).